# How can I denote content not covered under Creative Commons?

Tags: creative-commons, website, exceptions, books

[This Creative Commons Wiki page](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Marking_your_work_with_a_CC_license) says of the embedded license: "you might specify what 'work' you're talking about" and gives the example of prefacing the license with "Except where otherwise noted". How do I note otherwise? Let's look at two possible formats:

- A book in which Chapters 1--5 are CC, but Chapters 6 and 7 are not.

  - Is it enough to include a note in the front matter stating which chapters are not CC?
- A website in which the blog article content is CC but other elements, such as the logo, are not.

  - Does a disclaimer need to be posted next to the logo noting that it is not CC?

Comment: Are they CC because you, the rightsholder, have decided so to release them, or are they derivatives of CC *SA licensed work and must, in consequence, be released under a similar licence?

Comment: @MadHatter I am the rightsholder and wish to release my work as CC-BY.

Answer (score 2):

In both examples you give, the best option is to clearly describe what part is under which license at the point where you give the various licenses that are applicable to the work.

- In a book, there is likely some front matter stating the copyright licenses. There you can state something along the lines of

  > Copyright 2023 user5104897
  > Chapters 1 to 5 are licensed under <indicator of CC license, including a link to the license text>
  > Chapters 6 and 7 are licensed under <indicator of non-CC license>
  >
  > <Text of non-CC license>
- On a website, it is customary to have a page with licensing information. This is where you can mention that the blog text is under a CC license and that other parts of the site are under another license.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! Does this mean that it's enough to modify the standard CC license marking to say i.e. "MyBiz content samples and documentation are licensed under CC-BY", essentially using "MyBiz content samples and documentation" as the Title of Work in the CC License Chooser?